# MIB file design for SNMPv1

Tags: network-programming, snmp, mib

I'm a beginner in the SNMP field and just started reading about it.

I wanted to write a `mib` file so I could pass along that information.

I have a few questions to help guide:

Are RFC standards applicable to all versions of SNMP?

Different versions of SNMP syntax are different?

Comment: Please ask a narrower and more specific question. Have you read the standards yet?

Comment: At least you should read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol SMI v1 and SMI v2 are indeed different. So depending on which SNMP version you are targeting, you need to choose the corresponding SMI version.

Comment: ^ That is not true. SMI and SNMP are orthogonal. One describes a way to define a data model; the other describes a way to transmit data across a network. You can (and should) write a SMIv2 MIB and use any version of SNMP to transport data that relates to it.